# Hold back + preposition

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

As many other foreign English language learners, I often find myself struggling with English prepositions. This time, I came across an irreverent but funny sentence when I was watching a strange English movie a couple of days ago.

> ..But then, when did a single-figure IQ hold anybody back **in** the police force?

Although I think I understood its meaning, I was wondering whether the preposition IN is correct or not? Would "from entering/joining" have been a better choice in place of "in"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little additional context would be helpful in order to confirm the intended meaning of *[hold back](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/hold+back#hold_1__238)*; it is not clear whether someone would be holding back (active, e.g. not speaking), or would be held back (passive, e.g. prevented from taking an action or executing a plan; or prevented from advancing in his or her career).

I would interpret *in the police force* as saying that the person is already a member of the police force. In other words, the speaker is saying a single-figure IQ has never prevented any police force member from acting or progressing.

[In American English, we would more commonly say *on the police force*. People are *on* forces, teams, staffs, squads, committees, faculties, assignments, and other groups, though they are *in* the police, the army, the management, the sales department, the priesthood, and other institutions.]

If we were talking about joining the police, we could say somebody held back or was held back *from* the police force.

Comment: hmmm, the man whom the speaker was talking about was already a member of the police force. Perhaps, he meant that "a single-figure IQ" is not enough to prevent a fool from advancing in his career IN/on the police force. Therefore, the preposition IN might be right. Anyway, I'm not sure because I didn't get all the words he spoke. Thank you.